# Listen & Get Opened URL in Browser

Tags: android

Is it possible to listen to URL opening ? Like when the user open a website, I can get the Url he opened .

*No Spying, It's legal*

Comment: no. but it is possible to get url history if browser was registered as browser.

Comment: Hmm, Fair enough, Thanks.

Comment: yes, it is possible. You should hook the function with dll injection to browser.